# What series of tools would be best suited for a form collection and repository system within SharePoint?

Tags: document-library, form, document-template

I need to create a document library to hold temporary work instructions for a large company. The temporary work instructions are a controlled document or form which a person fills out online. Much of the form is standard and should not be editable by the user. Once saved/submitted it should automatically go to a list of approvers.  After it's approved another list of affected team members should be notified automatically as well. The finished form must be viewable, printable, stored online, kept indefinitely, locked from unauthorized edits.

There are so many different tools that I don't comprehensively know which to employ. Can someone give me an outline of how to achieve this?

SharePoint Document Library > MS Forms? > Power Automate? > Template Libraries? > Content Types?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I don't know where to start researching or which approach is best suited.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you stated yourself, there are many "roads to Rome" in this scenario. So for the best answer the requirements should be fleshed out a bit more and/or put into a diagram in order to plan the best implementation.

However, based on what you have layed out I would go about like this:

Create a Power App for the users to input relevant data. This gives the end users a nice way of putting in the data instead of filling out a document. Furthermore you can put input as mandatory and have some logic implemented like if they choose X then input field Y will appear. And of course the layout can be adjusted to your organisation visual identity.

The input from the power app will be stored in a SharePoint list. Once the user press save (or for instance save and send for approval in case theusers can srart up on the form and return later).

When the item is created on the list (potentially with an "ready for approval" metadata in case the user can return to the item) it will fire a Power Automate flow that will send the item for aproval at the right group of people (in the approval email you insert the data from the list item in order that the approvers doesnt have to click a link or an attachment, it can be styled to your needs).

Once approved the power automate flow will create a file* (either word or PDF) and store it at a suiteble library and assign the correct permissions for the item. Finally the flow will notify relevant people of the approval, potentially also including the generated document.

*in case you dont have premium connectors at your disposal use Ondrive connector with a service account.

So to sum up: Power apps - sharepoint list - Power automate - document library :)

Hope this can point you in a direction/starting point of building your application.Im sure that once you start off and other questions arise you can post here and people will be happy to help on more specific questions/errors :)

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I did not anticipate the use of a list for this type of task?  I was thinking more along the lines of an MSWord fillable form, put into a SharePoint document library, and set as a template.  I feel more comfortable from this angle.  Will it be possible after saving the file to trigger automatic approvers, and after approved, automatic notices to affected departments?

Comment: You are welcome :) Yes you can certainly do it as outlined with a document library and a flow that triggers when a file is created which will include an approval step and a notification step afterwards. Its a fine and robust way, but of course more limited in terms of business logic possible to implement.